# How to track & ID users in Google Analytics while registration/login via an other domain?

Tags: google-analytics, single-sign-on, analytics, google-analytics-api, userid

We have Multiple products, all are using one SSO (Single Sign On & Registration). So when visiting product A: **www.AAA.com**, the user (when register or sign-in) will have to go to: **sso.mainsite.com** to go through registration or login, then it will redirect him to the product page that he came from.

I want to track unique users properly so:

- I know each user from where he was acquired. (e.g. Mailchimp campaign? Social Media?..etc)
- Each user activity in the product is always linked to him (Made purchase, did an activity...etc)
- Statistics Not be affected by the common SSO site, where multiple product users are directed there to login or register. I want to be able to identify product A users.

We have Analytics Account for the main site (inc. SSO) and an account for product A. I'm having difficult time:

1. Should I use the product A tracking code in the SSO (to have multiple tracking codes on that page)?
2. Identifying users by Google's new User ID, should we let the SSO identify them (assign ID) or by Product A, when the user get transferred there?

I know i'm asking a lot, but i'm having difficult time knowing what is the best approach, not to damage any statistics. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to track the session on www.AAA.com without interruption it should be enough to add sso.mainsite.com to the referral exclusion list in the property settings in www.AAA.com's GA account.

That way sso.mainsite.com will not appear as a referrer, instead the session including channel attribution will be continued when you redirect back from sso.mainsite.com. This will completely ignore the pageviews on your sso page.

The alternative would be to set up cross domain tracking, if you want to include the detour to sso.mainsite.com into the tracking. That would be somewhat complicated, and unless you signal that this is really what you want I will not even bother to explain the setup.

Comment: would only adding it to referral exclusion list have downsides? My main concern is knowing who registered as a user and from what channels they came from. Some users come from email campaign directly to www.aaa.com and others go to registration page directly. Knowing X users registered from Twitter then did XYZ in the website and generated Z revenue is very important. That's why i want to do the optimal solution, even if it was complex. Thank you!

Comment: The downside is that you couldn't track the sign-on itself (at least not in the same account as the other interactions), only what happens before and after. The typical use case is payment gateways, as you do not want your transactions attributed to paypal et. al., but it should work for your use case since keeping the original traffic attribution is what referral exclusions are designed for.

Comment: Great, what about tracking user id? Earlier i was thinking in generating unique user id to google analytics in the registration page as it made more sense. Now is the best thing to do it after a user registered and came back to product page? Or before i direct him to SSO? I want to maintain from what channel each user was acquired even if he went directly to SSO first. (BTW, wont just adding prodcut A tracking codes in SSO pages as well solves this?)